# Chrome tabs to separate window after the fact?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

Chrome allows a tab to be dragged to a separate window. In practice, however, I only realize I want a separate window after I've opened several tabs on a particular topic, in which case I'd like them all in the new window together. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to Shift or Ctrl select tabs and drag them into a new window. You should also be able to right click and tab and have it select by opener or domain.

Answer (score 0):

My about:flags says it's not supported on OSX, but this might help - http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gCb_0gVhjnM